# Mercurial as a versioned data store

Tags: c#, database, version-control, mercurial

Instead of using an SQL Server `Posts` table with a matching `PostRevisions` table for flat-file (text/HTML) user content versioning, I'd much rather let Mercurial efficiently store changes for me and just keep track of where each user's file repository is.

This would make backups really easy, depending on how you wanted to share or shard content. The obvious solution is to have a single repository to store all user data, with folders for each user ID.

However, I have a bad feeling about performance and concurrency issues with this approach when committing files to repository storing millions of users' files.

Has anyone tried using Mercurial as a secondary data-store for flat user files?

Comment: What are you trying to version? The content of a content management system? Perhaps it would be wiser to actually use a CMS.

Comment: @Erno, I'm trying to version HTML snippets for my users.

Comment: What do you mean by HTML snippets? Really this sounds like a job for a CMS. Storage is not expensive so you need to have a lot of versions and a lot of users to make the approach you are suggesting worth the effort. Do you have any numbers?

Comment: @Erno, no numbers. Just an idea. By HTML snippets, I mean flat HTML content with many revisions. I agree with "storage is cheap", but I can't ignore the coolness of a DSCM :). What do you mean by a CMS? A CMS has to store content too and it's either unversioned files or a `FileRevisions` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're going take advantage of the stronger features a SCM system like hg offers I suggest you don't take this approach. Are you going to be using branches and merging? Probably not. So what do you really gain by using hg here? Backup is just as easy with a DB.

At the end of the day a RDBMS with a posts and revisions tables works just fine and are a stronger basis to build on than what's basically a file-locking based solution (hg, git, etc.). It would probably perform a whole lot better, too.

Btw, you should also evaluate document-oriented stores, like Mongo or CouchDB.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I am interested in branching, merging and efficient storage. Changes tend to be highly incremental and storing the entire document just to compare it again later, seems like such a waste.

Comment: Even though it seems that hg/git do such a fantastic job merging content, remember you'll still have to develop your own conflict resolution logic and UI. This is not that simple. So these features don't actually come for free. You'll have to parse any conflict by looking at the diff and then figuring out a conflict resolution UI for the user that's not as intimidating as a side-by-side diff/merge tool.. I don't know.. still don't think it's going to be less work with hg than with a DB.

Comment: Remember also that a SCM system is a complicated concept for developers, let alone users. Are you certain that you application would be to convey the concepts of branches/merges and conflicts to the user in a simple enough way? If I were you I'd try to find a ready-made client-side library that solves the problem of document merging. There is no 100% server side solution for this. I also don't think storing the entire document is a waste. You'll probably need to cache it anyway for fast retrieval, so I wouldn't start by optimizing this way.

Comment: +1 for "have to cache it anyway" and storage is cheap, and "complicated for developer, let alone users." I agree with you. Yeah, conflict resolution isn't simple. It was an idea, though! I've also been reading up on the locking issues, and it's better to use a database, which is designed to handle this type of concurrency.